# Arrange rows and columns in proper format

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I create a table layout and add rows and columns dynamically but when I add more data it does not display properly.

My output page looks like this (but this isn't the format I desire because it is not showing on one screen):

[image: screenshot]

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rltrackorder"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java code:

```
package shababpost.receiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


 public class Activity_Home_TrackOrder extends Activity {

    TableLayout table_parent;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayouthome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_track_order);
    init();
    }

    public void init() {

    relativeLayouthome = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltrackorder);

    relativeLayouthome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent trackordr = new Intent(Activity_Home_TrackOrder.this, Activity_TrackOrder.class);
        startActivity(trackordr);
        }
    });

    TableLayout table_parent = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);

    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
    tbrow0.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    //        tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 30);
    tbrow0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setText(" SR.No ");
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.addView(tv0);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(" Order Id ");
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText(" Date ");
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.addView(tv2);

    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv3.setText(" Amount ");
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.addView(tv3);

    TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
    tv4.setText(" Status ");
    tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.addView(tv4);

    TextView tv5 = new TextView(this);
    tv5.setText(" View ");
    tv5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tbrow0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tbrow0.addView(tv5);

    table_parent.addView(tbrow0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
        tbrow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 15);

        TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
        t1v.setText("1" + i);
        t1v.setSingleLine(true);
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);

        TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
        t2v.setText("#ASAS456" + i);
        t2v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t2v.setSingleLine(true);
        t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t2v);

        TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
        t3v.setText("09-March-17" + i);
        t3v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t3v.setSingleLine(true);
        tbrow.addView(t3v);

        TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
        t4v.setText("205 AED" + i);
        t4v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t4v.setSingleLine(true);
        tbrow.addView(t4v);

        TextView t5v = new TextView(this);
        t5v.setText("pending" + i);
        t5v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t5v.setSingleLine(true);
        tbrow.addView(t5v);

        TextView t6v = new TextView(this);
        t6v.setText("View" + "");
        t6v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t6v.setSingleLine(true);
        t6v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        t6v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.continue_btn_style);
        tbrow.addView(t6v);

        table_parent.addView(tbrow);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use a recyclervview instead

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  I have edited your question to improve the grammar and make it easier for people to understand, but it isn't clear what layout you want.  It would be good if you can edit your question to demonstrate more clearly the layout that you desire.  For future reference try to restrict your questions' content to only the things that people need to know to answer you; for example your screenshot doesn't need to be as big as it is and I suspect you could strip some code too.